# Sometimes I need to use external link with NavLink component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I use `react-router-dom` library `NavLink` component. Sometimes I need to use an external link in `NavLink` component but I get this as result:

`localhost:8080/https://google.com`

There is some default setting for it to distinguish between these cases, or better write my own?

Comment: NavLink is only for internal link, for external link, please use a href.

Comment: I have an array of data. Some of them are external links, some are links to this site. This is necessary for a possible flexible change in the future

Comment: I think you need to check if the link is internal or external, and decide if you should use NavLink or ahref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not to lose SPA

```
import React, {FC, PropsWithChildren} from "react";
import {NavLink as BaseNavLink, NavLinkProps} from 'react-router-dom'

const NavLink: FC<PropsWithChildren<{to: string} & NavLinkProps>> = ({children,to, ...props}) => {
  const regExternalLink = /(https?:\/\/)?[\w\-~]+(\.[\w\-~]+)+(\/[\w\-~@:%]*)*(#[\w\-]*)?(\?[^\s]*)?/
  const isExternalLink = regExternalLink.test(to)

  return isExternalLink
    ? <a href={to}>{children}</a>
    : <BaseNavLink to={to}>{children}</BaseNavLink>
}
```